# Is there a way to make a png image display the drop down menu?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a drop-down menu by clicking on a png.
I managed to make it work with text but when I try to replace it with `img src="menubutton.png"` as shown, the image appears to be clickable but the menu won't appear. I am new to this, am I missing something? Or maybe it just doesn't work like this?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: rgba(240, 159, 240, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #e98ebb3d;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f13b;
  min-width: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
  padding: 50px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.568);
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><img src="../photos/menubutton.png"></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home"><img src="../photos/music-notes.png"></a>
    <a href="#about">about</a>
    <a href="#contact">about</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It opens on click, but then closes it right away because of the window.onclick event handler. So just `onclick="myFunction(); return false"` will cancel its propagation.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: rgba(240, 159, 240, 0);
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover,
    .dropbtn:focus {
      background-color: #e98ebb3d;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #f1f1f13b;
      min-width: 50px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
      padding: 50px 50px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {
      background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.568);
    }
    
    .show {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction(); return false" class="dropbtn"><img src="../photos/menubutton.png"></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#home"><img src="../photos/music-notes.png"></a>
      <a href="#about">about</a>
      <a href="#contact">about</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you specify that the `event.target.matches('.dropbtn')` but when you are clicking on the image, that doesn't have the class `.dropbtn` on it, so it doesn't run the event.

If you were to change your button like this it will work.

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()"><img src="../photos/menubutton.png" class="dropbtn"></button>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: rgba(240, 159, 240, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #e98ebb3d;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f13b;
  min-width: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
  padding: 50px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.568);
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()"><img src="../photos/menubutton.png" class="dropbtn"></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#home"><img src="../photos/music-notes.png"></a>
      <a href="#about">about</a>
      <a href="#contact">about</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

There are other ways to write the code, but this should get it going for you!

Comment: Thank you both! I managed to fix my problem using this solution. However, the issue now is that my image has a white background when it was supposed to be transparent. I can't figure out what caused this.